Varying the arrowsize proportional to the linewidth in streamplots (matplotlib: 3.5.1)
I have fluid flow data, that has some vortices that decay in strength with distance in one direction. An easy example of this is below.
import numpy as np
# model flow field
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
U = (np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y)) * np.exp(-X)
V = -np.sin(X) * np.cos(Y) * np.exp(-X)

I would like to plot this with streamlines with arrows marking the direction of these streamlines, as below. Here, I plot the streamline width proportional to the flow magnitude.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create a figure with axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(3, 3))

mag = np.sqrt(U**2+V**2)
# Create a streamplot on the axis
lw = (mag/np.max(mag[10:,:]))
stream = ax1.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, linewidth=lw, arrowsize=1.5)

# Display the plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

But I would also like to have the arrowsizes proportional to the flow vector field magnitude, because otherwise the plot looks like below, with arrows randomly pointing in regions where there is no flow.

I have tried my best to get a workaround since this is not natively supported by the streamplot function, but I have not succeeded.
I have tried the below, to try and get the returned objects from the streamplot call, and somehow directly replot the arrows after rescaling. But this code does plots nothing!
# Create a figure with axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(3, 3))

# Access the arrow collection
arrow_coll = stream.arrows
line_coll = stream.lines
arrow_paths = arrow_coll.get_paths()

ax.add_collection(arrow_coll)

# Display the plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

After that I tried to brute-force get the mean locations of the original arrows and then try some other plotting strategy (maybe using a FancyArrowPatch call), but here as well I have hit a roadblock. I am unable to get the correct locations of the arrows in the axes coordinates of the original axis ax1. Below is how I tried to test this. But the scatter plot shows that the positions are incorrect and do not match those in the above streamplot.
# Create a figure with two axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(3, 3))

# Access the arrow collection
arrow_coll = stream.arrows
line_coll = stream.lines
arrow_paths = arrow_coll.get_paths()

transform = ax1.transData.inverted()
full_transform = arrow_coll.get_transform() + transform

for idx, path in enumerate(arrow_paths):
    vertices = full_transform.transform(arrow_paths[idx].vertices)
    pos = np.mean(vertices, axis=0)
    ax.scatter(pos[0], pos[1], marker='.')
    
# Display the plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Please help, as I am rather lost, and I do not really understand what is returned by the ax.streamplot() call. I would like to ideally re-scale the arrows in a similar way to the linewidth, but a solution somehow making them disappear where the flow-field is zero would also be fine.

At the moment you are plotting one arrow per streamline. Streamlines are not lines of constant velocity - as they follow flow it may speed up or slow down. Why plot arrows on your streamlines at all - why not just add them associated with the velocity field using ax.quiver - see https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html

Thanks for the reply. I have a contourf plot over which I overlay the streamplot. The reason I do not use the quiver plot is because (1) it does not look as clean as a streamplot overlayed over the contour plot and (2) unlike streamlines, the arrow field is not really good at showing the vortical structures, and their deformations, which is kind of the point of the plot that I am generating. The one arrow per streamlines is needed to show the direction of the vortices.

What are you contouring with contourf? If you want to show vortices then just contour vorticity (z component in your case) or the Q parameter: https://www.m4-engineering.com/q-criterion-for-vortex-visualization/  You will get colours from the opposite ends of the colour scale for the two senses of vorticity, and also a better sense of vortex strength.

The contour plot is the velocity magnitude. It is not really vorticity that I want to show, but the strength of the flow velocity and the vortex structures that it generates. It is non-turbulent flow.

Yes, but the velocity is zero at the centre of a vortex. You can still contour vorticity in laminar flow. I would plot line contours of the stream function over the top of a vorticity heat map. If the streamfunction levels are equispaced then their separation would give a good indication of local velocity magnitude.

Yes, you are right. But this is an indirect method. In my case the vorticity is not a relevant quantity, and the focus is really on the velocity magnitude and the structure of the velocity field. The velocity magnitude contours in the background are quantified by an appropriately scaled colorbar. Visualizing this through how densely packed the streamlines are is not a good option.

Arrowsize in                                                                                        streamplot
is a single number, scales them all.
How about this simple variant with more contrast ?
...
U = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * np.exp(-X / 3)  # exp(-x) is too much
V = - np.sin(X) * np.cos(Y) * np.exp(-X / 3)
mag = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig, ax = pl.subplots( figsize=[8,8] )
lw = mag / np.max(mag[10:,:])

ax.set_facecolor( "darkblue" )
stream = ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, linewidth=lw, color="lightyellow" )

print( "savefig streamplot.png" )
pl.savefig( "streamplot.png" )


You could also show mag in color (and at the mouse position), along the lines
extent = [x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()]  # should +- 1/2 pixel
ax.imshow( mag, cmap="YlOrRd", extent=extent )

